# Number of $n$ digit numbers, all digits are different, including $0$, and having no consecutive digits in consecutive positions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

I was reading [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2190881/number-of-9-digit-numbers-all-digits-are-different-and-nonzero-and-having-no) interesting question and I see that the general answer is the same of the Hertzsprung's problem ([A002464](https://oeis.org/A002464)).

Now if I consider the case including $0$ so the $ n $ digits are $[0, 1,..., n-1]$, what would be the answer? Of course the number can't start with $0$.

Comment: I don't see those problems as identical...the menage sequence just blocks permutations with $\sigma (i)\in \{i, i+1\pmod n\}$.  Am I misreading something?

Comment: You say you tested small numbers and found the ménage problem was the same as this problem. However, when $n=5$, there are $12$ valid permutations, namely $
(1, 3, 0, 2, 4), (1, 3, 0, 4, 2), (1, 4, 2, 0, 3), (2, 0, 3, 1, 4), (2, 0, 4, 1, 3), (2, 4, 0, 3, 1), (2, 4, 1, 3, 0), (3, 0, 2, 4, 1), (3, 1, 4, 0, 2), (3, 1, 4, 2, 0), (4, 1, 3, 0, 2), (4, 2, 0, 3, 1)$, $\tag*{}$ but the answer to the ménage problem is $13$. Is there something I am misunderstanding?

Comment: @MikeEarnest sure, as I said I just tried with small $n$ like $4$ and $5$ and the result is respectiveli $2$ and $13$

Comment: You say there are $13$ permutations, I listed $12$ of them. Which one am I missing?

Comment: @MikeEarnest no, you are right, I added a wrong one. I edit the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_n$ be the number of permutations of $[0,1,\dots,n-1]$ such that adjacent list entries are never consecutive numbers, as listed in https://oeis.org/A002464.

Let $b_n$ be the number of such permutations, where we additionally require the first element to be nonzero.

You can show that, for all $n\ge 2$,
$$
b_n=a_n-b_{n-1}\tag1
$$
Why? Because the permutations counted by $a_n$ fall into two classes; those whose first element is $0$, and those whose first entry is nonzero. There are $b_n$ permutations whose first entry is nonzero, by definition of $b_n$. If the first entry is zero, then the remaining entries must be a permutation of $[1,2,\dots,n-1]$ whose first entry is not equal to $1$, which is exactly the same as $b_{n-1}$.

If you iterate equation $(1)$, you get a formula for $b_n$ in terms of the numbers $a_4,a_5,\dots,a_n$:
$$
b_n=a_n-a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}-a_{n-3}+\dots+(-1)^{n-4}a_4\tag2
$$
Since the OIES page for $a_n$ does not give a closed formula, and $a_n$ can be written as $b_n+b_{n-1}$, we should not expect a closed formula for $b_n$. Therefore, the formula in $(2)$ is probably the best you can do.